# How to read the socket IO connection payload from nodeJS server

Tags: node.js, swift, socket.io

when initializing the socket connection from the swift client there's a send with payload method which i use to send the uid as payload

`socket.connect(withPayload: ["uid": uid])`

however I cant seem to be able to access this payload when receiving the connection event from the nodeJS server

```
io.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log("received connection", socket.request); 
    // Request does not include my payload
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into the same issue. Printing out the entire socket revealed that it's being stored in the `auth` variable. This should work:

```
io.on('connection', socket => {
    const payload = socket.handshake.auth
    const uid = payload["uid"]
}
```